# how to insert data inside columns in sql in subquery?

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

I am trying to solve this problem. Here is my question that I am trying to solve using SQL.

1. I have a project table which has many columns with data; such as (`ID`, `TITLE`, `DESCRIPTIO`,..ETC).
2. I have another table called field table; the field table has thousands of questions(it is similar to a survey poll with questions).
3. Each project has specific questions from the field table.
4. One of the questions in the field table is called `record_id`, some projects does not have this `record_id`.
5. Therefore, I sorted all the projects that does not have `record_id` using a SQL subquery; I was successfully able to sort the projects without `record_id`.
6. I am confused and stuck on how to use insert statement to insert `record_id` to those projects without `record_id`.

```
SELECT 
    PROJECT.PROJECTID
FROM
    PROJECT 
WHERE   
    PROJECTID NOT IN (SELECT PROJECT.PROJECTID
                      FROM PROJECT
                      JOIN FIELD ON PROJECT.PROJECTID = FIELD.PROJECTID
                      WHERE FIELD.ISPROJECTID = 1);
```

I have tried to use this query, but it is not working.

```
INSERT INTO FIELD (NAME, LABEL, DATATYPE, ALIGNMENT, ISPROJECTID)
VALUES ('record_id', 'Record ID', 'Text', 'RV', 1);

SELECT 
    PROJECT.PROJECTID
FROM 
    PROJECT 
WHERE 
    PROJECTID NOT IN (SELECT PROJECT.PROJECTID
                      FROM PROJECT
                      JOIN FIELD ON PROJECT.PROJECTID = FIELD.PROJECTID
                      WHERE FIELD.ISPROJECTID = 1);
```

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question. Can you please explain more?

Comment: MySql is not the same as Postgresql. Which one do you use?

Comment: sorry, I just used MySql.

Answer (score 1):

Most databases have an INSERT INTO SELECT.

you should check with the documentation of your database, if it differs

```
INSERT INTO FIELD (NAME, LABEL, DATATYPE,ALIGNMENT,
                   ISPROJECTID)  
SELECT 'record_id','Record ID','Text','RV', PROJECT.PROJECTID
                FROM PROJECT WHERE PROJECTID NOT IN
                 (
                 SELECT PROJECT.PROJECTID
                 FROM PROJECT
                JOIN FIELD
        ON PROJECT.PROJECTID = FIELD.PROJECTID
                WHERE FIELD.ISPROJECTID = 1
                   );
```

Answer (score -1):

what you need to insert, this  **VALUES( 'record_id','Record ID','Text','RV',1);** or you are select values from another tables!

if you insert from another table you should use like this VALUES => **select record1,record2,record3,record4,record5 from table**

Comment: that is not a valid code see my answer

Comment: Thank you for the feedback; when I run this query. I got this error. 

Assignment of a NULL value to a NOT NULL column "TBSPACEID=79, TABLEID=12, COLNO=1" is not allowed.. SQLCODE=-407, SQLSTATE=23502, DRIVER=4.26.14

Comment: @Yahai Alnuimi I am trying to hard code those values to those tables or I can also call them from other tables

Comment: A hint for your next answer: Better format code as code (using {} ) rather than making it bold.

Comment: @NewCoder  nbk answer's it valid, are you tried it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).